# Чтение чисел из файла и поиск наибольшего

Tags: java

Дана задача на нахождение наибольшего числа. Есть файл *chisla.txt*, содержащий числа `3, 8, 1, 5` в столбик. Необходимо в коде этот файл прочитать и найти наибольшее число.

Я знаю как вывести эти числа на экран и как прописав массив найти в нем наибольшее.
Но как соединить эти две задачи? Как прописать в коде этот "переход" с одной задачи на другую?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class X 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("\\chisla.txt"));
        //как их связать?
        int[] array = {...};
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {
            if (max < array[i])
                max = array[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Max: " + max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Так а вы изучали как работать с `BufferedReader`?

Comment: нас препод обучил так: рассказал историю, дал пару простых примеров, которые мы должны были разобрать самостоятельно и отправил в вольное плавание (мол, дальше сами).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раз всё же начали давать ответы, то с использованием Java 8 можно поступить так:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = null;
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("chisla.txt")))
    {
        array = in.lines().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    }
    catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (array != null)
    {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {
            if (max < array[i])
            {
                max = array[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Max: " + max);
    }
}
```

Все строки из файла, а точнее поток строк `Stream<String>`, возвращаемый `in.lines()`, привести к потоку `int`-чисел (`IntStream`, возвращаемый `mapToInt`) с помощью `Integer.parseInt`, после чего этот поток преобразовать в массив `int[]` с помощью `toArray()`.

Также нужно не забывать закрывать `BufferedReader` после чтения данных. В представленном коде это делается с помощью конструкции [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

А вообще, максимум можно находить и с помощью самого `IntStream`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("chisla.txt")))
    {
        OptionalInt optionalMax = in.lines().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).max();
        if (optionalMax.isPresent())
        {
            System.out.println("Max: " + optionalMax.getAsInt());
        }
    }
    catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Все понял!)))

Answer (score 1):

В массив закидывать не обязательно, вы просто можете прочитать построчно файл, сравнивая с текущим максимумом:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("\\chisla.txt"));
    String text;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    while ((text = in.readLine()) != null) { // читаем файл построчно
        if (Integer.parseInt(text) > max) // ищем максимум
            max = Integer.parseInt(text);
    }
    System.out.println("Max: " + max);
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: @Regent спасибо, поправил ответ

Comment: Думаю, ещё стоит учесть, что при возникновении исключения в 5-7 строках `in.close()` вызван не будет, что не есть хорошо. И мелкий момент по оптимизации: хорошо бы `Integer.parseInt` вызывать только один раз для каждой строки.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать сканер

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("tall.txt"));
int [] array= new int [100];
int i = 0;
while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
   array[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

и Ваш метод

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("\\chisla.txt"));
int [] array= new int [100];

String s =in.readLine();
int i = 0;

while(s!=null)
{

    try {
       array[i++] = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        continue;
    }

    s = in.readLine();
}

in.close();
```

Comment: Вот будет "здорово", если в файле окажется больше 100 чисел...

Comment: Это под его пример, а так нужно использовать ArrayList

Comment: "под его пример" можно и `int[4]` уж тогда.  Думаете, стоит учить людей плохому подходу, потому что "и так сойдёт"? А ну как у автора, на самом деле, не 4 числа? Или у будущих посетителей вопроса будет больше 100 чисел? И необязательно "нужно использовать" список - можно и массив.